# Saved output from putty not treated as regular txt

Tags: grep, putty

I saved the session output from putty to my windows desktop (puttyoutput.txt) and after that i uploaded it to my server. The problem comes when trying to grep the file (cat puttyoutout.txt |grep searchterm)

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Any ideea why this happens or how can i avoid it?

p.s. i'am also trying to grep for ips where i cant the -a option  (grep -aEx '([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' puttyoutput.txt)

Comment: might be some terminal control-sequences or a utf8-unaware grep that causes the problem. how does the file look like on the server? maybe ftp with text-mode? is puttyoutout.txt the same as puttyoutput.txt (or just a typo)?

Comment: The output of `file puttyoutput.txt` might be helpful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strings puttyoutout.txt |grep searchterm
```